# Excel ribbon: what is the difference between Office 2007 and 2010 part?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007, ribbon

I have been working with Custom Ribbons in Excel for quite a while now, and I've been using Office 2007 custom UI for backwards compatibility.

Does anyone know where I could find the differences between Office 2007 and 2010 custom UI? I'm just curious if there are any cases where I should use 2010 instead of 2007.

```
2007 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
2010 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
```

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Do a google search on `Office 2007 and Office 2010 custom UI schemas`

Comment: There are controls that don't exist ribbon xml in 2007, like context menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/xml-schemas.htm), the features added in Office 2010 are:

- ActivateTab
- ActivateTabMso
- ActivateTabQ
- autoscale
- centervertically
- getImage
- image
- ImageMso