# After update the MS Access 2007 to 2021 the custom ribbon is not visible anymore

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a custom ribbon for the Access application, which was developed in MS Access 2007 and was working fine but after having the new version of MS Access 2021 the custom ribbon is not visible anymore. It also does not show any error during the application start. Seems it cannot call the `onLoad` function in VBA from the XML anymore.

- I already enable `Show add-in user interface errors` from the `Options -> Client Settings`
- Allow the macros from the `Trust Center`
- Select `Microsoft Excel 16.0 Objects Library` in VBA

Any idea what is wrong?

Sample XML in `USysRibbons` table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="CustomRibbonLoad">
.....
</customUI>
```

Sample VBA (which should show the message-box on load but it does not)

```
Sub CustomRibbonLoad(ByVal ribbon As IRibbonUI)
   MsgBox "OnRibbonLoad"
End Sub
```

Comment: The XML schema was changed between Office 2007 and 2010, but you are already using the new one. But maybe something isn't compatible anymore? (Although it seems there was only things added). Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478004/excel-ribbon-what-is-the-difference-between-office-2007-and-2010-part).

Comment: The XML is totally fine (I have checked) but thanks for the link. I have the doubt it has some security issue during the installation. Not sure yet but have to check more.

Comment: My thought would be to create a brand new Database ... add *only* the necessary RibbonX (ie nothing more than `onLoad` and the necessary XML tags) and add *only* the necessary VBA (ie nothing more than the callback Sub, `CustomRibbonLoad` or whatever you want to call it). Ensure the VBA project compiles then save, close Access, re-open the Database and see what happens. If the callback is triggered then you know that MS has not done something weird with ribbon callbacks in Access 2021 and the problem you are experiencing lies somewhere in your Database ...

Comment: I did that but I couldn't reached at the `onLoad`  function. Somehow what I do it is not reacting.